# Gracefully exiting a QCoreApplication without flags and breaking out previous running code

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyside2

The following script results in following output when run and Ctrl+C is pressed.

```
>> SIGINT or CTRL-C detected. Exiting gracefully
Clean up
Return from loop due to stop
Final clean up
```

Is there are way to get a QCoreApplicaiton to quit without returning to the loop in infiniteloop? I would like to avoid using the flag and checking for it all time in different parts of the code. In other words, I want the program to capture the system event, clean up, and quit gracefully no matter what it may have been doing.

```
from signal import signal, SIGINT
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QTimer


class App(QCoreApplication):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super(App, self).__init__(args)
        self.__stop = False
        self.aboutToQuit.connect(self.finalcleanup)
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.infiniteloop)

    def finalcleanup(self):
        print('Final clean up')

    def cleanup(self):
        print('Clean up')

    def handler(self, signal_received, frame):
        print('SIGINT or CTRL-C detected. Exiting gracefully')
        self.__stop = True
        self.cleanup()
        self.quit()

    def infiniteloop(self):
        while 1:
            if self.__stop:
                print('Return from loop due to stop')
                return
            getinput()


def getinput():
    try:
        x = input('>> ')
        print(x)
    except:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App(sys.argv)
    signal(SIGINT, app.handler)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My set up:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.7
- PySide2 5.13.2

I want to use Qt because my final application will benefit from the signal/slot model.

Comment: Calling quit() on your QApplication will do just that. Qt cleanup code usually relies on a running eventloop (i.e. some destructors are only called by finished() signals), so there's no cleaner way to exit than to tell the QApplication to quit whenever it has finished its current event-workload. Everything else won't be a clean exit, though a clean exit is usually not high on the priority list for most applications.

Comment: Basic rule of a GUI: The tasks executed within the main thread (where the GUI lives) must consume very little time (maximum a few milliseconds), if not, then it could cause unwanted behaviors, in that case the solution is to execute that logic in another thread.

Comment: @markus-nm I was worried that this may be the only way to do this. Eventually this program will interface with hardware that I don't want to leave in a floating (unknown) state. This code allows me to leave it in a good state, but returning to the loop could put it right back into a different state.

Comment: @eyllanesc I agree and I could/should spin my major code in another thread, but in my experience Qt threads still have the same problems of having to use flags to exit the Qthread.run (or connected worker) code. I guess I was hoping to have something like terminate(), were I could run some clean up before the Qthread was killed by the os.

Comment: I don't subclass QThread, but use worker (QObject), another option I use is `threading.Thread(daemon = True)`